# Question regarding eigen values of matrix $N$ given $MN+N^{T}M=3I$ , where $M$ is symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Let $M$ be any $3\times3$ symmetric matrix with eigen values $1$,$2$ and $3$. Let $N$ be any $3\times3$ matrix with real eigen values such that $MN+N^{T}M=3I$ ,where $I$ is identity matrix .Then which of following cannot be eigenvalue(s) of $N$ ?

(a) $\frac 1 4$

(b) $\frac 3 4$

(c) $\frac 1 2$

(d) $\frac 7 4$.

Now if we take  $N=\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 &0\\0 & b &0\\ 0&0&c\end{bmatrix}$ and $M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0\\0 & 2 &0\\ 0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$ then $MN+N^{T}M=3I$ gives $a=\frac 3 2$ ,$b=\frac 3 4$ and $c=\frac 1 2$.

So by choosing this **particular** example we can discard  option b an c . Any hints for rest options?

Comment: Try to permute the values $1,2$ and $3$ in martix $M$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalues of $N$ with eigenvector $v$, we have that
\begin{align*}
3
= v^{\mathrm{T}}(3I) v
= v^{\mathrm{T}} MN v + v^{\mathrm{T}} N^{\mathrm{T}} Mv
= 2\lambda\cdot v^{\mathrm{T}}M v.
\end{align*}

But $\lambda_{\min}(M) \leq v^{\mathrm{T}}M v \leq \lambda_\max(M)$, so this yields that
$$
\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{\lambda_\max(M)} \leq \lambda \leq \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{\lambda_\min(M)}.
$$

Comment: $\lambda_{\min}(M) \leq v^{\mathrm{T}}M v \leq \lambda_\max(M)$  it is true for any matrix $M$ ?

Comment: @MeetPatel It's true for $M$ symmetric, but not true in general. Take
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$